# VBoxManage setextradata command does not add avx2 to /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Linux & VirtualBox noob here, so please go easy.

I've been running into problems compiling code with scipy in a VirtualBox 5.2 VM running Fedora 26 on my host Windows 10. The cryptic error output is "*Illegal instruction (core dumped)*". I believe the issue is scipy thinks the VM has AVX2 enabled when it doesn't (**grep flags /proc/cpuinfo** confirms that neither AVX nor AVX2 are enabled).

Going off of this askubuntu thread, I tried running **VBoxManage setextradata $VMname VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2** on the host. This seemed to work fine, and running **VBoxManage getextradata $VMname enumerate** even confirms the change (*Key: VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2* now shows up with a value of 1, as expected.)

But when I reboot my VM (or even when I reboot all of VirtualBox, just in case), **grep flags /proc/cpuinfo** shows that AVX and AVX2 are still absent from my flags. I don't understand why **VBoxManage** sees AVX2 now enabled but **/proc/cpuinfo** does not. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seeing what you just set using `vboxmanage getextradata enumerate` does not necessarily mean the setting was set correctly.  The VirtualBox extradata is basically a key/value store, so no matter what you set, even if you use the wrong key, it will show up when you enumerate.

Comment: Is there a different key/value that will make this work?

Comment: Still an issue in 2023 - cannot activate AVX,AVX2 for guest Ubuntu on Win10 host. Followed steps from the question and didn't get instructions AVX,AVX2 in the guest OS.